# Usage of BULK COLLECT and dbms_sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was reading more on BULK COLLECT and usage of dbms_sql and tried to apply the same for one of my procedure
In my stored procedure the core logic is an INSERT into a table from the values of another table as

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE My_procedure (pi_date       IN DATE,
                                          po_error      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                          po_error_desc OUT nocopy VARCHAR2)
AS
  curr_date DATE;
BEGIN
    CURR_DATE := PI_DATE;

    INSERT INTO t1
                (col1,
                 col2,
                 col3,
                 col4,
                 col5)
    SELECT t2.col1,
           t2.col2,
           t2.col3,
           t2.col4,
           CURR_DATE
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             PO_ERROR := -1;

             PO_ERROR_DESC := 'proc nam : '
                              || 'my_procedure'
                              || ', err_num :'
                              || SQLCODE
                              || ' | , err_msg :'
                              || SQLERRM;

             ROLLBACK;

             DBMS_SESSION.free_unused_user_memory;
END;
```

However since the Data that is going to be inserted into another table is huge, in my second modified procedure

I have used BULK COLLECT and dbms_sql as below

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE My_procedure (pi_date       DATE,
                                          po_error      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                          po_error_desc OUT nocopy VARCHAR2)
AS
  v_curr_date DATE;
  l_col1                       dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table;
  l_col2                       dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table;
  l_col3                       dbms_sql.Number_Table;
  l_col4                       dbms_sql.Number_Table;

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   t2;

BEGIN
    V_CURR_DATE := PI_DATE;

    PO_ERROR := 0;

    OPEN c1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 bulk collect INTO l_col1, l_col2, l_col3, l_col4 limit 1000;

        forall indx IN 1..l_col1.COUNT
          INSERT INTO t2
                      (col1,
                       col2,
                       col3,
                       col4,
                       col5)
          VALUES      (L_col1(indx),
                       L_col2(indx),
                       L_col3(indx),
                       L_col4(indx),
                       V_CURR_DATE);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             PO_ERROR := -1;

             PO_ERROR_DESC := 'proc nam : '
                              || 'my_procedure'
                              || ', err_num :'
                              || SQLCODE
                              || ' | , err_msg :'
                              || SQLERRM;

             ROLLBACK;

             DBMS_SESSION.free_unused_user_memory;
END;
```

So here is my second example, I have used BULK collect as per the documentation however

Can someone poinpoint the exact usage of `dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table`?

As shown above if the actual length of col1 is VARCHAR2(40) but `dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table` uses `VARCHAR2(2000)`

```
TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Comment: What's your exact question? Your provided code is riddled with syntax errors. You should provide the exact sources you're working with and mention what's the problem you're running into

Comment: My question is the approach that I have used in the example second of using BULK COLLECT and using dbms_sql to do an INSERT into another table is correct or not . Hope this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your bulk collect loop needs to be a full loop as you are using a `LIMIT` clause:

```
-- Open the cursor
OPEN cursor_name;
-- Loop through cursor records
LOOP

   -- Fetch the cursor results into a collection limited to a set figure
   FETCH cursor_name BULK COLLECT INTO table
   LIMIT 1000;

   -- For every record in the collection
   FORALL x IN INDICES OF table
      INSERT INTO target_table
      (col)
      VALUES
      table(x);

   -- Set up the limit loop exit criteria
   EXIT WHEN table.COUNT < 1000; -- Less that the limit you set    
-- End the loop
END LOOP;
-- Close the cursor
CLOSE cursor_name;
```

This pseudocode snippet should get you started on the right path for getting your bulk code to work. Your current declaration of the `DBMS_SQL` tables looks fine.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks My question regarding dbms_sql is As shown above if the actual length of col1 is VARCHAR2(40) but dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table uses VARCHAR2(2000) and as per oracle documentation varchar2_table is TYPE varchar2_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; so why to use 2000 space when actual length is 40?

Comment: It's a handy constructor for quick and efficient use of a table holding `VARCHAR2` values. If you are genuinely worried about the extra bytes being used by an array of VARCHAR2(2000) then create your own collection to use with a max length of 40. `TYPE array_40_chartype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` Then declare a table using the type: `array_40_char array_40_chartype;` voila.

Comment: Thanks Ollie in your example FETCH cursor_name BULK COLLECT INTO table , here table is a type of a collection right ?

Comment: Yes. It's a collection. I usually use associative arrays to bulk collect into.